# Insert a div in a random location in a list of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that looks like so:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

I was wondering if there is a way that I could insert a div **randomly** between any of the "item" divs, so when the page is loaded, it would look like:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="rondomDiv">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
</div>
```

All the divs with the "item" class are dynamically generated, and cannot be modified. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sure it's possible. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Post the code that you have tried. Surely it's possible! One approach could be that you store the ID's of the items into an array then pick up a random index from that array and then after or before it add a random div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest, pending further information:

```
$('.item').eq(
    /* I'm using the eq() method to select a specific element,
       and creating the random number (in the range from 0-(number-of-elements))
       within the method to avoid creating unnecessary variables. */
    Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.item').length)
    /* after() creates an element from the html string, and inserts it after
       the element selected earlier with the eq() method */
).after('<div class="random"></div>');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F8ZcA/).

A slightly altered, though more verbose, alternative to the above:

```
$('<div />', {
    'class': 'random',
        'text': '...'
}).insertAfter($('.item').eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.item').length)));
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/F8ZcA/1/).

References:

- [`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/).
- [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
- [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

Comment: Thanks! Was struggling to get the other solutions to work, but for some reason your "verbose" solution worked immediately! You're a life saver!

Answer (score 4):

Try something like below,

```
var $items = $('#container').find('.item');
var pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * $items.length)

$('.randomDiv').insertAfter($items.eq(pos));
```

Comment: Thanks Vega, I'll give this a quick try, and be back with some feedback.

Answer (score 1):

### Code:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">

</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i =1; i<10; i++) {
        $("#container").append("<div class='item' id='"+i+"'>Item</div>"); /*adding item divs dynamically */
    }

    /*the real magic is below */
    var rand_id = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1); /*generating an item divs ID randomly */
    $("#"+rand_id).after("<div class='randomDiv'>Random DIv</div>"); /*adding the random div after that div of the rand_id */
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mareebsiddiqui/ULcTc/

### Explanation:

This is simple. First I add the `item` divs dynamically by giving them ID's respectively with starting from 1 and ending on 10. Then I generate a random ID using `Math.floor()` and `Math.random()` JavaScript functions. Then I fetch(using a simple technique) the div with that random ID and then after that div I add a random div.

Comment: It's dynamically generated because the OP wants its to be! and has an ID so that I can address a particular div! @DavidThomas

Comment: "All the divs with the "item" class are dynamically generated" <-- this is what the OP said! So to create my fiddle I needed to add that! :)

Comment: Ah...I misread that, originally, I read it for some reason as 'all the divs *within* the 'item' class are dynamically generated.' My apologies (and thanks for the clarification!), have an up-vote... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
var $items = $('#container .item');
$items.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * $items.length ))
        .after("<div class='rondomDiv'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not provide code if you tried nothing.

But if you don't know where to start and need a workflow :

Coun't the number of div in container Create a random number between 0 and the number of div.

Append your div after the div with the random number index.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
function randomDiv() {
    var divCount = $(".item").length;
    var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*divCount);

    $("div.item:eq(" + randomnumber + ")").after("<div class='randomDiv'>hey im random</div>");
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/meaFv/

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where the non-jQuery answer is equivalent to the jQuery answer, in terms of lines of code:

```
// Assuming you already have a reference to the random div at "randomDiv"
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var position = Math.floor(Math.random() * container.childNodes.length);
container.insertBefore(randomDiv, childNodes[position]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/qbqfR/ Press RUN a bunch of times to see it in action.

```
var x=Math.floor(Math.random()*$('#container').children().length);

$('#container div').eq(x).append('<div class="rondomDiv">YAY</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
itemLength = $('#container .item').length; //quantity of .items
randomPlace = Math.floor((Math.random()*itemLength)); //some random from 0 to .item length

randomDiv = $('<div />',{
    'class':'randomDiv',
    text: randomPlace
}); //.randomDiv

$('#container .item').eq(randomPlace).after(randomDiv); //place it after the .item of position 'randomPlace'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/4tpCy/