# Insert div into random location inside a container of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

**How do I insert a div into a random location inside a container of divs?** Similar to [Insert a div in a random location in a list of divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238255/insert-a-div-in-a-random-location-in-a-list-of-divs) except I'm not using a list.

Right now it appears inside a random container div, not randomly inside the container itself:

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/QXdL3/15/

HTML:

```
<div class="template" style="display: none;">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/75/150">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150">
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150">
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var template = $('.template').find('.image').clone(),
  target = $('.main'),
  targetChildren = target.find('.image'),
  random = Math.floor(Math.random() * targetChildren.length);

targetChildren.eq(random).append(template);
```

Comment: is `targetChildren.eq(random).parent().append(template);` what you want?

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately that places the template after the last div, not randomly amongst them.

Comment: Could you please provide an image of what is currently going on, along with an image of what you would like to achieve. Your details are not specific and are quite confusing.

Comment: Oh understood :). `targetChildren.eq(random).before(template);` then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close!

Instead of `.clone()`, try using `.html()` like my example below.

Also, I slightly changed your loop along with the random number generator.

Works very well now. Refresh the page to see three random kitty photos added somewhere within the other images.

[**WORKING EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QXdL3/18/)

Comment: Anytime @MarkBoulder - Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You just need to change `append` to `after`; change:

```
insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).append(insertionTemplate);
```

To:

```
insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).after(insertionTemplate);
```

Your current code inserts the new div into another div as follows:

```
<div class="image" style="position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 310px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150">
  <div class="image" style="position: absolute; left: 225px; top: 310px;">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/75/150">
  </div>
</div>
```

The new version will produce the following:

```
<div class="image" style="position: absolute; left: 150px; top: 310px;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150">
</div>
<div class="image" style="position: absolute; left: 225px; top: 310px;">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/75/150">
</div>
```

Comment: your `random` must be between 0 and the number of total length of children. you have neglected to mention that tiny part.

Comment: Good point!! I believe that's already taken care of by the OP's code `var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * insertionTargetChildren.length)`

Comment: Appreciate the help !

Answer (score 1):

This will put it in random position:

```
random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (targetChildren.length+1));
if(random > targetChildren.length){
   target.append(template);
}else{
    targetChildren.eq(random).before(template);
}
```

The `targetChildren.length+1` is to add the possibility of appending in the last place ;)