# Insert randomly but never next to each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

Based on [Insert a div in a random location in a list of divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238255/insert-a-div-in-a-random-location-in-a-list-of-divs) -- I'm trying to randomly insert some cat photos into a div of non-cat photos:

http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/QXdL3/21/

**But is there a way to prevent the cats from appearing next to each other sequentially?** They should be spread out.

JS:

```
var insertionTemplate = $('.template').find('.image').html(),
    insertionTargetChildren = $('.main').find('.image'),
    insertionFrequency = 3;

var random;
for (var i = 0; i < insertionFrequency; i++) {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * insertionTargetChildren.length) + 0;
    insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).append(insertionTemplate);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="template" style="display: none;">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/75/150" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>

    <!-- ... -->

</div>
```

Comment: Appearing next to each other as in sequentially, or next to each other in terms or margin/padding/spacing?

Comment: @j08691 thanks for pointing that out! Sequentially. Updated question.

Comment: looks like you used some plugin in your demo, don't forget to mention it in your question, and if it has some corresponding tag, also tag it.

Comment: You know you're not really inserting a template, but just sticking the image in with another random image ?

Comment: @KingKing the plugin was irrelevant, however I've removed it from the demo.

Comment: Just a quick note - in your jsfiddle you're probably looking for the `<code>` tag, instead of styling `<span>`s with CSS.

Comment: @adeneo nice catch! I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Joeytje50 very cool I had no idea that tag existed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed the issues and made a check to see if the next or previous element is a cat.

```
var target    = $('.main').find('.image'),
    frequency = 3,
    element   = $();

for (var i = 0; i < frequency; i++) {
    (function getElems() {
        element   = target.eq( Math.floor(Math.random() * target.length) );
        var next  = element.next(),
            prev  = element.prev(),
            all   = element.add(next, prev);

        if (element.hasClass('cat') || next.hasClass('cat') || prev.hasClass('cat')) getElems();
    }());

    var template  = $('.template div').clone(true);
    element.before(template);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QXdL3/26/)

Comment: @MarkBoulder - made some changes, that first class check didn't work properly, but it should now.

Comment: Little bit curious, why can't `var template` be amongst the other vars?

Comment: Also, Patrick Gundersen's example below, in particular: "this is a bit more efficient since you only need to inspect the precise objects you are inserting against, rather than inspecting every image" -- should we add something like that to ours?

Comment: I gave the `text/template` thing a go but I'm not sure it's worth the hassle: http://jsfiddle.net/frank_o/QXdL3/29/

Comment: @MarkBoulder - If you stick with getting the template as a string you could have the template outside the loop, but I decided to clone the template instead as I think it's better to work with nodes instead of strings, and then it should be inside the loop otherwise we'd be targeting the same clone every time.

Comment: As for efficiency, you can do a replace on the entire list outside the loop, and that would make it faster, and probably a lot faster than the answer by Patrick Gunderson below. I've added some timers to see how long the logic and insertion takes to both, here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/QXdL3/30/** and here **http://jsfiddle.net/kf2zU/2/**, and my solution seems to be three times faster.

Comment: Taking that a step a further and sticking it in jsperf shows that Gundersons solution is amazingly slow, it's so slow I think I must have done something wrong in jsperf, but I can's spot any errors, so I guess it's just incredibly inefficient -> **http://jsperf.com/for-loop-vs-gundersens-while**

Answer (score 1):

Within your loop you could check to see whether the number generated is equal to the last number that was generated +-1

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/QXdL3/22/

```
for (var i = 0; i < insertionFrequency; i++) {
    random = Math.floor(Math.random() * insertionTargetChildren.length) + 0;

    if (random != excludeNumA && random != excludeNumB) {
       insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).append(insertionTemplate);
    }
    excludeNumA = random + 1;
    excludeNumB = random - 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a but that @adeneo just pointed out. Should I close this question while I try to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You can shotgun the list, like the above answers, but this is a bit more efficient since you only need to inspect the precise objects you are inserting against, rather than inspecting every image.

Add 2 steps. The first should shuffle the array of images so that they're in a different order every time. The second should create an array of insertion points into the other list. If you don't want cat images to be next to each other, then make sure your list of insertion points, is at least spaced by 2.

You should also use `<script type="text/template">` tags for your templates.

http://jsfiddle.net/kf2zU/1/

### HTML

```
<script id="cat-template" type="text/template">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/75/150" />
    </div>
</script>
<script id="img-template" type="text/template">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
</script>
<div class="main">
</div>
```

### JS

```
var catTemplate = $("#cat-template").html();
var imgTemplate = $("#img-template").html();

//place images into .main
var $main = $(".main");
var numImages = 50;
for (var i = 0; i<numImages; i++){
    $main.append($(imgTemplate));
}

//make a list of cat images for example
var numCatImages = 50;
var cats = [];
for (i = 0; i < numCatImages; i++){
    cats.push($(catTemplate));
}

//shuffle the cat list so they appear in random order
cats = _.shuffle(cats);

//create a list of insertion points
var insertionPoints = [];
var insertionIndex = 0;
var minSpacing = 2;
var maxSpacing = 8;
var spacingRange = maxSpacing - minSpacing;
while(insertionIndex < numImages){
    insertionIndex += Math.floor(Math.random() * spacingRange) + minSpacing;
    insertionPoints.push(insertionIndex);
}

//place cat images at the insertion points
//it's important to start from the end and work your way forward so the previous insertions don't mess with subsequent insertion points
//so we reverse the array of insertion points

insertionPoints = insertionPoints.reverse();
var catIndex = 0;
_.each(insertionPoints, function(insertionIndex, i){
    $main.children().eq(insertionIndex).after(cats[catIndex++]);
});
```

Comment: Wow this is really cool. I had no idea about the script template tag! But isn't @adeneo's answer a lot simpler?

Comment: @adeneo's solution is simpler, but far less efficient. My solution minimizes the steps needed to insert the cats, while adeneo's requires you to check multiple properties on multiple elements every iteration. For small lists this is probably trivial, but for large lists my solution will be orders of magnitude faster. My solution is also tunable so you can control spacing better.

Comment: This has been a great lesson in code efficiency.. thank you.. I really appreciate it..

Comment: I'd probably mark this as correct except in my case the cats themselves don't need shuffling, and the Lorempixel images are pre-existing server-side ones. Hope I can buy you a beer some day though!