# Inserting images - Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, jquery

Expanding on the accepted answer at [Insert randomly but never next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23983903/insert-randomly-but-never-next-to-each-other) (http://jsfiddle.net/ny1mc9kw/) -- does anybody know why I'm getting:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
jQuery.fn.jQuery.get @ jquery.self.js?body=1:118
jQuery.fn.extend.add @ jquery.self.js?body=1:2947
getElems @ self.js?body=1:13
```

I'm getting this error in Chrome with my in Ruby on Rails app but unfortunately I'm unable to reproduce it in the fiddle.

```js
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238255/insert-a-div-in-a-random-location-in-a-list-of-divs

var target = $('.main').find('.image'),
    frequency = 3,
    element = $();

for (var i = 0; i < frequency; i++) {
    function getElems() {
        element = target.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * target.length));

        var next = element.next(),
            prev = element.prev(),
            all = element.add(next, prev);

        if (element.hasClass('cat') || next.hasClass('cat') || prev.hasClass('cat')) {
            getElems();
        }
    }
    getElems();

    var template = $('.template div').clone(true);
    element.before(template);
}


$('.main').packery({
    itemSelector: '.image'
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
span {
    font-family: Monospace;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: #666;
    background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://packery.metafizzy.co/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<h2>Randomly insert <span>insertionTemplate</span> into <span>insertionTarget</span> N times (<span>insertionFrequency</span>)</h2>

<div class="template" style="display: none;">
    <div class="image cat">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/75/150" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/75/150" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a debugger, see where the error is. Replicate in a MCVE. Ruby is a server technology, jQuery and your error are client side. Ruby is irrelevant for this context.

Comment: Looks like all (or at least, too many) of your image elements (`target`) do have the class "cat", and therefore your recursion doesn't terminate but overflow.

Comment: @Bergi I don't know, there's only one `.cat`. I know it's difficult since I can't reproduce it, but I'm working on it.