# Weird output with packery used to randomly position div

Tags: jquery, packery

I'm having trouble with inserting a div (ad banner) randomly within a bunch of other divs.

I found the working example I'm using from this question: [Insert a div in a random location in a list of divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238255/insert-a-div-in-a-random-location-in-a-list-of-divs)

However, my template is being inserted within one of the items/children, rather than it's outer container/target.

Here's my html:

```
<div class="template" style="display: none;">
    <a class="item advertisement">
        <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
            <img alt="image" src="http://placehold.it/525x765">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="listings">

    <a class="item card" href="#">
        <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/525x765">
        </div>
    </a>

    <a class="item card" href="#">
        <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/525x765">
        </div>
    </a>

</div>
```

The JS

```
    var insertionTemplate = $('.template').find('.item').html(),
        insertionTarget = $('.listings'),
        insertionTargetChildren = insertionTarget.find('.item'),
        insertionFrequency = 1;

    var random;
    for (var i = 0; i < insertionFrequency; i++) {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * insertionTargetChildren.length) + 0;
        insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).append(insertionTemplate);
    }

    $('.listings').packery({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });
```

And this is what I get in the output:
(notice `.item-inner-wrapper` is placed within the last `.item`, rather it's parent `.item` being placed within `.listings`)

```
<div class="listings">

    <a class="item card" href="#">
        <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/525x765"></div>
        </div>
    </a>

    <a class="item card" href="#">
        <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
            <img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/525x765"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="item-inner-wrapper">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/525x765" alt="image">
        </div>
    </a>

</div><!-- [END] listings -->
```

What have I got wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace `append` to `after`

```
 var insertionTemplate = $('.template').find('.item').html(),
            insertionTarget = $('.listings'),
            insertionTargetChildren = insertionTarget.find('.item'),
            insertionFrequency = 1;

    var random;
    for (var i = 0; i < insertionFrequency; i++) {
        random = Math.floor(Math.random() * insertionTargetChildren.length) + 0;
        insertionTargetChildren.eq(random).after(insertionTemplate);
    }

    $('.listings').packery({
        itemSelector: '.item'
    });
```

Comment: That's almost there, it places it inline with the others now, however for some reason the "item" html is still being removed.  Screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wyxw6in3k4680w8/Screenshot%202015-10-05%2010.18.10.png?dl=0